# Confluent-kafka (with kerberos) Error when spark-submit python job in cluster Mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, cluster-mode

I am facing the following error while submitting a python job in a cluster mode:

> appcache/application_1548793257188_803870/container_e80_1548793257188_803870_01_000001/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/**init**.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from .cimpl import (Consumer,  # noqa ImportError: librdkafka.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

librdkafka and other python dependencies are installed ONLY on an edge node.
Before submit, I create a virtual environment and pip install confluent-kafka in the following way:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --no-binary :all: confluent-kafka
```

After that, I create environment.tar.gz and pass it to spark-submit with --archives

I have tried to set spark properties like that:

```
--conf spark.executorEnv.LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/.libs"
--conf spark.driver.extraLibraryPath=/usr/lib64:environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/.libs"
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.LD_LIBRARY_PATH=environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/.libs"
```

But unfortuantly it didnt work!

Somebody faced the same problem?

Comment: Spark has its own Kafka libraries (written in Java, and uses Java Kerberos API). Not clear why you are trying to add `confluent-kafka` Python library into that

Comment: https://github.com/markgrover/spark-secure-kafka-app#spark-secure-kafka-app

Comment: The problem is that the job is written in python, consumer is of confluent-Kafka. And it s not possible to change the implementation.

Comment: I don't follow... the Spark Streaming Kafka implementation is written in Scala, but you're welcome to use PySpark to directly call that. You can't include the confluent-kafka Python code within Spark, and you need to use the Spark Context, not just a regular Python script with any library. https://medium.com/@mukeshkumar_46704/getting-streaming-data-from-kafka-with-spark-streaming-using-python-9cd0922fa904

Comment: Indeed I am using spark context within my python job. Any way, the problem was solved installing the  librdkafka on each worker node of the cluster.

Comment: That's still the incorrect way to use Spark with Kafka...